# How do I efficiently hash a Polars dataframe?

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to implement some caching logic on a function that acts on a Polars dataframe (this is all in Python).

To avoid needlessly re-computing the result, it'd be great if I could quickly check if the dataframe has changed - ie. a hash comparison.

I am currently using:

```py
_my_hash = df.hash_rows().sum() # int
```

But curious to know if there are better options.

Comment: Polars dataframes are not hashable on purpose, see https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9743

Comment: I agree conceptually, and by it's nature (hashing large objects) I'm not expecting perfection - but can you propose a hashing function? I see some codebases use id(df) as the hash.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need from a hash, but in my case I needed a hash to enable caching of jobs. This function worked well for that:

```py
import mmh3
import polars as pl


def hash_dataframe(df: pl.DataFrame, seed=42) -> str:
    """Hash a polars DataFrame. Due to the behaviour of pl.DataFrame.hash_rows 
    this will only be consistent given a polars version.
    Args:
        df (pl.DataFrame): polars DataFrame to be hashed.
        seed (int, optional): Seed for the hash function.
    Returns:
        str: Hash of the polars DataFrame.
    """
    row_hashes = df.hash_rows(seed=seed)
    hasher = mmh3.mmh3_x64_128(seed=seed)
    for row_hash in row_hashes:
        hasher.update(row_hash.to_bytes(64, "little"))
    return hasher.digest().hex()
```